# OS X Yosemite - Cannot log into MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, macos, phpmyadmin

I know this issue has been addressed before in other threads but so far none of their solutions worked. So I'm opening a new one...

I've used this [Tutorial](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/) to setup a local wordpress page on my Mac (I'm running OS X Yosemite). But unfortunately every time I try to log into phpMyAdmin @ http://localhost/~usernam/phpmyadmin/index.php I get this error message: "(!) Cannot log in to the MySQL server "

Although if I log into mySQL through the terminal the same usernam/password work just fine.

I'm really not sure what's wrong and like a said I tried every solution suggested in any of the other threads with no success. Is there a way to troubleshoot via the terminal and print out what might be wrong so I could post it here?

Here is my config.inc.php

```
<?php
/*
 * Generated configuration file
 * Generated by: phpMyAdmin 4.4.7 setup script
 * Date: Mon, 25 May 2015 05:28:33 +0000
 */

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'MYPASSWORD';

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '5562b2e8dedaf8.08870882';
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
?>
```

I've noticed, that when I change `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';` to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';` I'm able to access the database but Wordpress ist still having trouble connecting...

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: What's the error message reported by WordPress?